# Sort my data then only edit data within the sort

Tags: vba, excel

So long story short I'm working on a large data set and I want to cut slices out and edit them in groups so my idea was to tell vba to sort the data and then apply edits to the sorted list. However, it seems as though it applys these changes to everything including titles that didnt make the sort.

```
Range("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=* Manager *", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
rng.Replace " IT ", " IT, "
rng.Replace " Manager ", " Manager, "
```

[image]

As you can see here, despit the IT title not being included in the sort the code still applied a comma to it. Is there any viable way to ensure that These edits are only applied to the currently sorted list?

EDIT: Someone requested the full code so here goes.

```
Sub Title()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") > 0 Then
        cell.Value = " " & cell.Value & " "
    End If
Next cell
rng.Replace "  ", " "
'Data Breakdown

'Remove phrases
 rng.Replace "at *", ""
rng.Replace "We're *", ""
rng.Replace "We are *", ""
rng.Replace "we're *", ""
rng.Replace "we are *", ""

Range("B:B").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=* Manager *", _
        Operator:=xlAnd

rng.Replace " IT ", " IT, "
rng.Replace " Manager ", " Manager, "
```

Comment: how is `rng` defined and set?

Comment: @A.S.H Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

Comment: @MedicatedGorilla can you post the rest of your relevant code ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Updated the post

Comment: `rng.Replace` will apply to the `rng` Range, not to whatever you have sorted  or selected before. Here your `rng` includes `B3`, so the replace applied to `B3`, you should not be surprised. Call `Replace` to the range you sorted, and you will have it applied to it.

Comment: @A.S.H any good way to define the sort as a range? I cant know for sure what info is coming through every time so I can't redefine the range by hand every time. I need something that can define itself.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$2")`, the range you just auto-filtered?

Comment: @A.S.H doesn't seem like that would work. Well I guess I shouldn't have assumed there was a good way to do it like that.